# Chrome webpage inside a Tk frame

Tags: google-chrome, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to run my chrome page inside a Tcl Tk frame. And I have to run my scripts from windows platform... As of now I am able to start the chrome page using the start command. How do I enclose my chrome page inside Tk window?

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] http://www.gmail.com
```

Thanks

Comment: That really ought to be `exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" http://www.gmail.com` but that won't affect your question substantively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. You can embed applications into Tk frames using the [-container](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/frame.htm#M9) option which informs Tk that this frame will be used to host third-party windows. You then have to pass the window id (`winfo id $frame`) to the application so that it knows to use this Tk frame as its parent. There is an example [embedding mplayer](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13059) on the Tcl wiki and uses mplayer's -wid option. I can see no option in chrome (nor in chromium) that would accept a window to embed into. There is a [chromium embedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) project which may be worth looking into.