# How to display html page inside tcl/tk window?

Tags: tcl, tcltk

When we click on a button, it opens separate tcl/tk window and display some html inside that window with scroll option available.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering HTML is *intensely* complicated. Try [Tkhtml3](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/index.html).

See also:

- [Chrome webpage inside a Tk frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602706/chrome-webpage-inside-a-tk-frame) (I don't think the answer that is there helps… but if it had a good answer then we'd be tempted to close this question as a duplicate).

Comment: CSS is very complex; DOM and JS is worse. And far too many web pages need all of that in order to work even close to correctly. And everything is a very dynamic target… but for simple pages like embedded documentation, something like tkhtml will have a good chance to work fine.