# How to embed an application in a Tk window/frame?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

If it is possible to embed an application in a Tk window, would you'd please point me to the correct methods?

I'm experimenting with something like: `firefox -P "ToolTest" -no-remote -new-instance -private -kiosk -url "http://127.0.0.11:8000/study"` to open a browser to the local server url.

I read about the `-container` option for frames and the [Entice](https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2007/papers/Steve_Landers/Entice.pdf) paper that used [TkXext](http://stu.oc9.org/TkXext/fossil/artifact/d2f2ad8adb67c622) that obtained the window id and reparented it. However, TkXext is not in Tclib and I'm not clear on whether or not it is still used and what platforms it'll work on.

It appears that it's easy to do so using Tkinter, at least according to this [geeks for geeks example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-a-website-in-a-tkinter-window/); but I'm using Tcl/Tk only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two key steps:

1. You should make the `frame` with `-container 1 -background {}`. That prepares Tk to handle another application doing things with it and disables drawing the background.
2. You get the XID of the frame with `winfo id $theFrame` and get the other program to use that as its primary drawing surface. The XID will be the ID of a `Window` at the C level.

   If this is Tk, you do this with the `-use $id` option to a `toplevel` at creation time (an argument to `wish` when you launch it for `.`). Other applications have their own mechanisms for this; consult their documentation (or find a suitable Stack Overflow answer).

Note that on Windows and macOS, you're unlikely to make this work except between two instances of Tk. They do drawing surface IDs in a different way.

Comment: Under windows you probably need `winfo_frame` and use something (like in python) `int(TheFrame.winfo_frame(), 16)` to get the hexadecimal value.

Comment: Thank you. I think this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602706/chrome-webpage-inside-a-tk-frame) and its [link](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+to+embed+a+non%2DTk+GUI+into+a+Tk+frame) to a wiki.tcl about embedding is similar to the process you outlined. It also appears that the TkXext took a different approach of reparenting the application in the Tk window for applications that do not accept some sort of flag/option for embedding, such as the `-wid` in the media player example in the cited link.

Comment: I also read over a few questions on SO about interating over the processes and attempting to find one with a parent window and using it. Perhaps, that is similar to TkXext in that it searches by name.; but I did not study that code to identify what it really does. I downloaded it but thought I'd ask before spending a great deal of time attempting to learn something that may be outdated. I was interested in doing this with a browser, and it may not be worth it anyway since Chrome-based browsers appear to all have an `-app` option that sort of opens the url in a separate window.